# Javascript For Loop for password verifying not working

Tags: javascript, html

Code :

```
<script>
function getLoginInfo(){
var loginname[1]="login";
var loginpwd[1]="pwd";
var loginname[2]="marcoyeung";
var loginpwd[2]="infotalkong";
}
getLoginInfo();
var captchaCorr;
function generateCaptchaImage(){
var captchaImage=document.getElementById("captchaImage");
var captchaNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
switch(captchaNumber){
case 1:
captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/4020820.jpg";
captchaCorr="3H1O";
break;
case 2:
captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/4387355.jpg";
captchaCorr="63VD";
break;
case 3:
captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/2027648.jpg";
captchaCorr="B8T7";
break;
case 4:
captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/6532820.jpg";
captchaCorr="B23N";
break;
case 5:
captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/1239866.jpg";
captchaCorr="C1BS";
break;
case 6:
captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/4505395.jpg";
captchaCorr="DAB3";
break;
case 7:
captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/2555220.jpg";
captchaCorr="H2KF";
break;
case 8:
captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/3738849.jpg";
captchaCorr="H84H";
break;
case 9:
captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/6334357.jpg";
captchaCorr="JD84";
break;
case 10:
captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/3832297.jpg";
captchaCorr="YTEU";
break;
default:
generateCaptchaImage();
break;
}
return false;
}
function checkPassword(name,pwd,captchaInput){
var captchaInputTemp=captchaInput;
captchaInput=captchaInputTemp.toUpperCase();
captchaInputTemp=""
for (var i=1; i<loginname.length; i++;){
if name=loginname[i]{
if pwd=loginpwd[i]{
window.location.href="member.html";
}
}
}
}
</script>
<h1>LOGIN FORM</h1>
<form action="">
Login Name : <input type="text" name="loginname"><br>
Login Pwd : <input type="password" name="loginpwd"><br>
Captcha : <input type="text" name="captchaInput" id="captchaInput" maxlength="4" size="4">
<input type="submit" onclick="checkPassword(this.form.loginname.value,this.form.loginpwd.value,this.form.captchaInput.value);return false;" value="Login"><br>
<img id="captchaImage" src="" />
</form>
<script>
generateCaptchaImage();
</script>
```

Captcha Image cannot show in a correct way. No `src`.

How can I change it? I added `getLoginInfo()` to make more than one password ok.

The photo became a file broken icon. I can do nothing. when i inspect element, img src became `""`.

Please help.

Comment: Besides you actual problem, you render any password/captcha protection useless, if you check them on the client side. Anybody can look in the code and extract the correct inputs.

Comment: Just a note; doing your password check like that in Javascript makes it very easy to bypass. Anyone could look at the HTML and see the users and their passwords, not to mention the URL that members are redirected to. You'll need something serverside to provide a more secure form of authentication.

Comment: Your code syntax is full of errors..

Comment: Yes, i know. Could someone edit it to provide help for me a bit? i can't really correct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell you the truth, I think that the best way to help you would be not helping you doing this. As other people have told you, this *'security system'* you've developed is not just bad, it's malicius. Every browser's got developer tools know, meaning it's very easy to bypass your *'security'*.

Think that if you're creating a captcha protection system, is to avoid malicius people trying to create a programmatic way to access your page. Any person with enough knowledge to do this wouldn't need it with your method. I think, in fact, that they'd laugh.

So, first of all, I hardly encourage you to implement server-side security and not this. However, warning given, I've corrected your code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nm7an/1/).

```
<body>
<script>
var loginname = [];
var loginpwd = [];
function getLoginInfo(){
    loginname[1]="login";
    loginpwd[1]="pwd";
    loginname[2]="marcoyeung";
    loginpwd[2]="infotalkong";
}
getLoginInfo();
var captchaCorr;
function generateCaptchaImage(){
    var captchaImage=document.getElementById("captchaImage");
    var captchaNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
    switch(captchaNumber){
        case 1:
            captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/4020820.jpg";
            captchaCorr="3H1O";
            break;
        case 2:
            captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/4387355.jpg";
            captchaCorr="63VD";
            break;
        case 3:
            captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/2027648.jpg";
            captchaCorr="B8T7";
            break;
        case 4:
            captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/6532820.jpg";
            captchaCorr="B23N";
            break;
        case 5:
            captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/1239866.jpg";
            captchaCorr="C1BS";
            break;
        case 6:
            captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/4505395.jpg";
            captchaCorr="DAB3";
            break;
        case 7:
            captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/2555220.jpg";
            captchaCorr="H2KF";
            break;
        case 8:
            captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/3738849.jpg";
            captchaCorr="H84H";
            break;
        case 9:
            captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/6334357.jpg";
            captchaCorr="JD84";
            break;
        case 10:
            captchaImage.src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/9/25398845/3832297.jpg";
            captchaCorr="YTEU";
            break;
        default:
            generateCaptchaImage();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
function checkPassword(name,pwd,captchaInput){
    var captchaInputTemp=captchaInput;
    captchaInput=captchaInputTemp.toUpperCase();
    captchaInputTemp="";
    for (var i=0; i < loginname.length; i++){
        if (name==loginname[i]){
            if (pwd==loginpwd[i]){
                window.location.href="member.html";
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
<h1>LOGIN FORM</h1>
<form action="">
Login Name : <input type="text" name="loginname"><br>
Login Pwd : <input type="password" name="loginpwd"><br>
Captcha : <input type="text" name="captchaInput" id="captchaInput" maxlength="4" size="4">
<input type="submit" onclick="checkPassword(this.form.loginname.value,this.form.loginpwd.value,this.form.captchaInput.value);return false;" value="Login"><br>
<img id="captchaImage" src="" />
</form>
<script>
generateCaptchaImage();
</script>
</body>
```

There were lots of syntax errors thers. I suggest you to learn more Javascript and programming before trying to build security systems.